# Why is the four coloring theorem so hard to prove when the five/six theorem proofs are much more accessible?

Tags: graph-theory

I might be giving a talk to high school students soon. I plan to show them the proof for the six/five coloring theorems and also give a brief discussion of the famous four color theorem.

Why is the four color theorem *so* much harder to prove than the six/five color theorems? Is there a rather elementary reason for this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the fix/six theorems? At first, I thought you just meant proving that any planar graph can be colored in 6 colors, an then, even tighter, five colors. But that doesn't seem to quite qualify as "variants."

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Perhaps "variants" isn't the right word; I'll make an edit.

Comment: You can show that three colors is false. So, the four colors is harder because you are getting closer to a false statement.

Comment: But the four color theorem is *much* harder: six/five color theorem  proofs take at most a page while the four color theorem proofs takes ~200 pages with help from computer algorithms. There has to be a better reason.

Comment: This is a difficult question. Observing that we don't have a simple proof is one thing, but proving that there is no simple proof is *much* harder. – One reason could be that the four-color-theorem is just barely true: You have to exclude thousands of marginal cases one-by-one.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter That is a plausible response...but is there a more concrete answer? Perhaps there's a characterization that covers looser cases but not the case when colors = 4?

Comment: @JunichiKoganemaru Why to assume any sort of continuity (nearby cases being easy to prove implying it should be easy to prove) if we are talking about discrete problems in discrete cases?

Comment: I'm not saying that it should be easy, but the enormous gap in difficulty is rather suspicious to me. I guess @ChristianBlatter's answer is somewhat satisfying. 5 color theorem is too loose and the 4 color theorem is just barely true.

Comment: One funny related fact is that there is a formula for the number of colors needed on a 2d surface with $n$-holes. The formula works for any $n$, and the formula return $4$ for $n=0$, the sphere/planar case. But there is a (relatively) easy proof for the formula for $n>0$ which doesn't work for $n=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews could you provide a reference for this? that sounds very interesting and it could be what I am looking for

Comment: The formula is on the wikipedia page for the four color theorem. I was slightly wrong - it works for orientable surfaces, but fails to give the exact value one non-orientable surface, the Klein bottle. It was proven, except for $n=0$, in 1968. @JunichiKoganemaru  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Generalizations

Comment: I think finding hard limits often is much harder. The Reimann Hypothesis can be expressed as an upper bound of a function, for example. I wonder if one can find a problem where an upper bound is 5 but it is actually undecidable whether $4$ is an upper bound. :)

Answer (score 1):

The chromatic number of a graph imbedded in a genus p surface is $ \chi(S_p)  =  {\left\lfloor \frac{7 + \sqrt{1 + 48 p}}{2}\right\rfloor} , p \ge 1 $ where ${[x]}$ is is the largest integer not greater than $x$.     I was fortunate enough to take Gerhard Ringel 's  class  on this subject, ( he proved equality in the formula  in 1968) . I would still recommend "The Map Color Theorem" as a text in combinatorics . We did not study the proof of the case $ p = 0 $ of course where the chromatic number remarkably fits the formula but proof had been absent until Haken - Appel and the computer proof of 1976. I have no idea why things progressed in that manner, it's a very good question. The history of the proof is a little like the history of the Poincare conjecture.

Comment: You should say that the chromatic number is $at \ most$ that much. Also it is interesting to note that a similar formula holds for non-orientable surfaces, except for the Klien bottle, for which it is off by 1.

Comment: No, now you've got it wrong ! The chromatic number of a graph is an invariant of the graph.

Comment: Exactly, so embedding the graph into two surfaces of different genuses won't change the chromatic number of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the book [Topological Graph Theory by Gross and Tucker](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486417417.html). The chromatic number of the torus is 7, I suggest having a torus ready with 7 regions, which, I recall, are hexagons. This was first proved by Heffter in 1891. Heawood's upper bound was 1890; I guess the year discrepancy was about the chromatic number possibly being smaller than seven. Anyway, pages 217 and 218 especially. Also Figure 3.31 on page 137. The hexagon thing is the dual of 3.31.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, is it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, perhaps not. People often  ask about the wrong aspect of the topic they bring up.

Comment: Yeah, it's a badly enough posed question, I'm actually surprised it isn't closed yet. :)

Comment: Sorry for the ill posed question. I was just curious.